# Retrofit2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Call$Factory in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, retrofit2, okhttp, imgur

> I am not developing a Android Application ,  
>   I'm just writing some JAVA codes to support Imgur API services.

```
public interface ImgurAPI {
    String server = "https://api.imgur.com";
    String BASE64 = "base64";

    @POST("/3/upload")
    void postImage(
            @Header("Authorization") String auth,
            @Query("title") String title,
            @Query("description") String description,
            @Query("type") String type,
            @Body String base64Image,
            Callback<ImageResponse> cb
    );
```

}

Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ImgurAPI.server)
                .build();
        ImgurAPI myAPI = retrofit.create(ImgurAPI.class);
        String base64Image = new ImageReader(PATH).getBase64String();
        myAPI.postImage(AUTH, "Hi", "Test", ImgurAPI.BASE64, base64Image, new MyCallBack());

    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the exception throwing :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Call$Factory
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Call$Factory
```

I found out lots of solutions of Android.
So I'm wondering if Retrofit available in **only JAVA**. 
thanks .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it ,
If you are writing Java (Only Java), 
And you downloaded the Jar of Retrofit2,
It might not contain certain libraries which built-in in Android Studio,
So you have to download them manually.

1. OkHttp3 [OkHttp3 3.0.0 Jar download](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.0.0-RC1/okhttp-3.0.0-RC1.jar)
2. Okio [Okio 1.6.0 Jar download](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.6.0/okio-1.6.0.jar)
3. Retrofit-converter gson [Retrofit converter gson-2 beta3 Jar download](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/retrofit2/converter-gson/2.0.0-beta3/converter-gson-2.0.0-beta3.jar)
   (If you want to convert other types of data , just download other Jars in [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters) )
4. Gson [Gson 2.2.3 Jar download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gson/gson-2.2.3.jar.zip)

Import the jar files , then It could work

Make sure you got all of its[image]

Comment: Hello,

I'm having the same problem. I added all the JARs manually, EXACTLY like in my Android application (I'm doing a project using Retrofit on the server this time, on the endpoint that gives information to the Android application) but I get the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Call$Factory" error. I can't seem to find a way to solve it yet.

Comment: the links seem all down or the site dead

Answer (score 5):

If you find this post when looking for a solution after getting this error when you use the Influxdb-java.jar in a Java EE project, you will need the following dependencies:

- OKHttp3: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.9.1
- Retrofit2: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.3.0
- Moshi Converter for Retrofit2: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-moshi/2.3.0
- Moshi: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.moshi/moshi/1.5.0
- Okio: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.13.0
- OKHttp3 logging interceptor: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor/3.9.1

It was annoying to sort this out, so hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

> If you find this post when looking for a solution after getting this error when you use the Influxdb-java.jar in a Java EE project, you will need the following dependencies:

For anyone attempting to get influx-java to work, and as an update to the answer above: There are actually a lot more dependencies involved. A single file with all the dependencies can be found [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.influxdb/influxdb-java). Extracting this file and adding all the contents to your project should solve any issues.