# Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory Reported exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Callback

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, logback

I am using java 8. I tried to add pushing logs to SPLUNK.
Added library `splunk-library-javalogging-1.8.0` and `janino-3.1.9` and second appender in logback.xml file

```
<appender name="http" class="com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender">
    <url>https://splunk.net:9999</url>
    <token>12345azxc-d089-1243-3123-8b5819f30d97</token>
    <source>${env}</source>
    <sourcetype>hive</sourcetype>
    <host>${host}</host>
    <messageFormat>text</messageFormat>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%msg </pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

but when I try to start application I have an error:

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Callback
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender.start(HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender.java:77)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
```

Comment: Find out which dependency contains okhttp3.Callback and add it? Is that the only error in your logs?

Comment: yes, but I see a lot of libs with `okhttp3` e.g `com.squareup.okhttp3` doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Call$Factory in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111504/retrofit2-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-okhttp3-callfactory-in-java)

Comment: @juanlumn, not really, question which you found is for Android and I already added `okhttp3` and still there is the same problem. I tried diff versions e.g `4.9.1`, `3.2.0` and `5.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

regarding this: https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging/issues/235

for java8:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

works instead of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```